# Cross join in Excel or SQL

Tags: sql, excel, cross-join

I am using Gephi to create a network graph, here is a small subset of the data that I have:

```
ID  Label
1   Sleep quality   
2   Stress  
3   Healthy Eating  
4   Tremor  
5   Balance 
6   Drooling    
7   Exercise    
8   Mood    
9   Speech  
10  Parkinson's On-Off
```

So I want my graph to have these 10 nodes.

Then for the edges, I have:

```
Source Target   User
1       5       5346
5       4       5346
4       7       5346
7       6       5346
6       9       5346
9       3       5346
3       2       5346
2       8       5346
8       10      5346
```

The "User" column is something I have added to explain the problem I am having. I am using a big database (in SQL) to obtain this data. On a mobile phone app, users select 10 of the different choices available (as listed in the nodes). In SQL I can query the data easily so that I can obtain the 10 choices of each of the users.

It is easy to create a graph with the edges with the information in the edges table but I would also like to connect each edge to all other edges, this is important for me. So for example, 1 connects to all those in "target". Then 5 connects to all those in "target" and so until all nodes are connected to each other for each user.

I can do this manually but the original data set has 2000+ users and this will take a long time. I know that there is a way of using cross join, possibly in Excel or in SQL... but I'm unsure how to do this..

Thanks!

Comment: Connecting an edge to all other edges is not at all clear what you mean and your explanation isn't helping much either. Can you share what your desired output might look like. Even if it's for just one user so that we can understand how to massage the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can drop this cross join into your SQL:  (It'll list all Source's with all possible Target's.)

```
   (SELECT e.Source as Source, n.ID as Target
      FROM
      (SELECT DISTINCT Source FROM tblEdges) as e
      cross join (SELECT DISTINCT ID FROM tblNodes) as n
      ) as xCross
```